# Wordpress not reflecting changed of the database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, migration

my problems started when I moved my website to another folder (from /dev/ to /).
I have gone through the whole database in order to change all the hardcoded /dev/ into / but I still notice that wordpress, somehow, still uses the old values.

Basically the website uses information that are not there anymore.
I checked my own and the server cache and they all seem to be clean (the server doesn't even seem to have that feature on).

So, I am pretty much lost...

Comment: Did your name servers point to dev?

Comment: What do you mean? I changed both site URL and wordpress URL to the correct one. The database is still the same as well as the User.

Comment: I'll admit that I'm stepping way outside my area of expertise here, but I'm aware that sometimes people buy a domain name, 'park' it, and then point that domain's "name servers" at some other address. If that's not a "top level" address then I guess something like the problem you describe could occur - but probably best to speak to your host - they're sure to be able to help, just because this kind of problem must occur so frequently.

Comment: I have the top level address. I am directly at www/.

Comment: Try to clear the dns cache of your computer

Answer (score 1):

When you move a wordpress install, you need to change the site URL throughout your database. To do this you'll need to export your current database via PHP MyAdmin, and then use a tool like:

http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

...to do a search and replace on the entire database.

Search for:
www.yourwebsite.com/dev

replace with:
www.yourwebsite.com

Then import the new database, open your Wordpress site via wp-admin and re-save permalinks.

Answer (score 1):

Run this query in your database

```
set @oldurl = 'http://oldwp-url.com', @newurl = 'http://newwp-url.com';

UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, @oldurl, @newurl) WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = REPLACE (guid, @oldurl, @newurl);
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, @oldurl, @newurl);
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, CONCAT('src="', @oldurl), CONCAT('src="', @newurl));
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = REPLACE (guid, @oldurl, @newurl) WHERE post_type = 'attachment';
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE (meta_value, @oldurl, @newurl);
```

Comment: Thanks. But I think the problem was mainly in the revision number. So, I fixed but "just" re-adding all the info again...

Comment: gud atleast your issue got fixed